# Spawn EACCES error when using ghostscript with firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried using ghostscript to convert pdf to image in a cloud function, and have been running into this spawn EACCES error for ages now and I still can't figure it out.

Im following this link
[Cloud Functions for Firebase - Converting PDF to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242998/cloud-functions-for-firebase-converting-pdf-to-image/47368129)

But i keep getting this error.
[image: EACEES error]

Any knows anything about this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i ll recommend that you use some other npm package for conversion. these commandline utilites in firebase are not easily debuggable and may break when you have users online. so searh for packages on npm

Comment: The problem is that almost every npm package out there for converting pdfs to image has ghostscript dependency.

Comment: still it ll help you because they maintain their code and if you find a lib having more than 1k weekly installs. you can try that